# I need to display whether the input given in the JSP page is valid by checking the Data in Database using servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I have to enter the valid Cad number in the JSP page and I need to check whether this cad number is a Autocad by checking in the Database select query in servlet.
Display the result in the JSP page if the entered cad number is a Autocad or not.

Servlet Page;

```
@Jpf.Action(forwards = { @Jpf.Forward(name = "cadCheck", path = "/com/new/checkCad.jsp") })
protected Forward checkCadAvailability(CadForm cadForm) throws SQLException {

        String  username = cadForm.getUsername();
        String cad = cadForm.getCad();
        String password = cadForm.getPassword();
        int response = -1;
            String cadResult ="";
            Connection con = null;

            try 

                       {
                CenterDataAccess dataAccess = new CenterDataAccess();
                con = dataAccess.getConnection();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("In cadCheck::Error in CenterDataAccess", e);
            }

            if (con != null) {
                PreparedStatement masterSt = null;
                 String sql= "SELECT CAD FROM CAD_INFO  WHERE CAD  = '"+cad+"' AND  Auto_cad ='Y'";

                     masterSt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

                ResultSet rsMaster = masterSt.executeQuery();


                while (rsMaster.next()) {
                   cadResult = rsMaster.getString("CAD");

                }



                    if( cadResult.equalsIgnoreCase(cad))
                       {
                       cadForm.setErrorMessage("Cad Number is a Auto CAd  applicable");

                      }

            }

        return new Forward("cadChekTest", cadForm);
    }
public static class CadForm extends FormData {

        private String password;

        private String username;

        private String cad;
        private String errorMessage;

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getCad() {
            return cad;
        }
```

I have to display the message whether the provided cad number is auto cad or not .but I am not getting any result even though i entered the valid cad

Comment: did you got any error ?

Comment: I am not getting any error or any message

Comment: Try tp print `cad` check if it has something in it or not .Also that's not right way to use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).